# LinearLayout not centering correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

Good afternoon everyone.

I have two LinearLayouts one under the other. Both include two centered buttons.

I need that white space between buttons on top layout and on bottom layout match without change width buttons.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_contenedorContador">
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_botonRespuesta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_textoPregunta">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quiz_falso" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quiz_verdadero" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_botonNav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_botonRespuesta">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/quiz_atras" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quiz_siguiente" />
            </LinearLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFizw.png)

**UPDATE**

Here I show an image that indicates how I want the distribution. The red line is only to guide

[Image how I want the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II2FB.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share the dummy design of expected layout?

Comment: I want the white space between the top two buttons  match with the white space in the bottom buttons. I updated with new image. @AndroidGeek

Answer (score 1):

change

android:weightSum="2" of linearlayout and  button width is android:layout_width="0dp"
and add layout weight line android:layout_weight="1".

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_botonRespuesta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_textoPregunta">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="falso" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="verdadero" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_botonNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_botonRespuesta">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="atras" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="siguiente" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. But that code change the buttons width. I need that white space between buttons on top layout and on bottom layout match without change width buttons.

Comment: you can set margin to buttons for white space.

Answer (score 0):

use tablelayout instead two linearlayout

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_botonNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_botonRespuesta">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="falso" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="verdadero" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="atras" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="siguiente" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```